# Can I use a url to view my workbench application by browser like i use for phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, workbench

Hi I am new to workbench and I have migrated from phpmyadmin to workbench recently and I want my workbench to be accessed from my laptop which is connected with my system. I usually do by logging it with the ip address of my system like 192.164.xx.xx/phpmyadmin. Is it possible for me to view like the same in workbench please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show workbench in a browser. It is a seperate program. You have to install workbench on your notebook too.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, So After I install workbench on my notebook I can  connect to mysql on my main system using the ip address right?

Comment: right. Depends on your firewall settings. You have to allow the incoming connection.